# Prove the existence of a holomorphic primitive

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: D(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be continuous and holomorphic on $D(0,1) \setminus \left]-1,1\right[$ such that  for all $a,b,c \in D(0,1): \int_{[a,b,c,a]}f(z) \, dz=0$.

I have to prove that $f$ has a holomorphic primitive

What I did:
I searched any theorems that could help. but I only found the contraposition: if $f$ has a holomorphic primitive then integration over any loop is 0.

Could you please help? Any hints much appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: Looks like an application of Morera's theorem for triangles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem#Weakening_of_hypotheses.

Comment: Thank you! It actually proves the holomorphic character of $f$ but doesn't tell about the holomorphic character of its primitive

Comment: A holomorphic function on a simply-connected domain has a holomorphic primitive. –  But  if you look at the proof of Morera's theorem then you'll that it works by proving that $f$ has a holomorphic primitive $F$ (which then implies that $f = F'$ is holomorphic as well).

Comment: Thank you, I've read the construction of the holomorphic derivative in the proof of Morera's theorem. There is this step I don't understand: Then using the continuity of ƒ to estimate difference quotients, we get that F′(z) = ƒ(z), could you please help me decipher this ?